# can't delete multiple object with blank spaces and Cyrillic in file_name using REST API, google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, fileserver

My batch delete code looks like:

```
  @staticmethod
    def gcs_batch_delete(gcs_file_names):
        logging.debug('Deleting ' + str(len(gcs_file_names)) + ' files.')

        boundary = '===============7330845974216740156=='
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'}
        data = '--' + boundary + '\n'
        template = """Content-Type: application/http

DELETE /storage/v1/b/%s/o/""" % os.environ['GCS_BUCKET_NAME']
        bodies = [template + urllib.quote_plus(filename) + '\n' for filename in gcs_file_names]
        data += ('\n--' + boundary + '\n').join(bodies)
        data += '\n--' + boundary + '\n'

        logging.debug('Request:\n' + data)

        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch'
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, payload=data, method=urlfetch.POST, headers=headers)

        logging.debug('urlfetch result: ' + str(result.content))
```

So, when i delete multiple objects, its only delete a files with latin characters and files, that haven't blank spaces in name. But, also, on the site files disappear, but not from google cloud storage.

Guys, can u help me upgrade this code? :3

Answer (score 2):

urllib.quote_plus will replace spaces with pluses, but "+" is a valid character for a Google Cloud Storage object name, so this isn't what you want.

Try using percent escaping instead (for space, that's %20).  You can use  urllib.pathname2url to do this.